# How can I save http_accept_charset into my database like http_user_agent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, http, server

After login, I want to save user's agent information and user's http charset.

Here, I can save user agent info with $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT');. But How to save http_accept_charset into DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand that [`$request->server()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_server) is retrieving its data from the [`$_SERVER` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). I would expect `$request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET')` to work, then. Please take note that this header is purely optional and may not be present at all.

Comment: I have tried with $request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET') but it doesn't work. then I have checked with dd() ,it returns null.